# Angularjs Update the View in all the machines

Tags: angularjs, view, auto-update

After adding the values into the database then, how can I update the view with that added data in all the machines witch are opened the application at a time with out refreshing the page.

I am using the PHP. I am posting one post and giving the comments to that post. When I entered post or comments it will display in all the browsers when i posted in my browsers.

Comment: Please elaborate and also show what you have tried so far. There has to be some form of trigger that tells the UI that the database has been updated. Either some trigger from the server or a continuously polling service call from the UI.

Comment: Please, let us know more about the issue

Comment: What kind of language you are using of your backend server side?

Comment: I am using the PHP. I am posting one post and giving the comments to that post. When I entered post or comments it will display in all the browsers when i posted in my browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to use `$interval` to go off and fetch the latest data, and then update the model

for example:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('someController', ['$scope', '$interval', '$http',  function(scope, interval, http) {
        scope.modelUpdater = inteval(function() {
            http.get('url').success(function(data) {
                // update model here with whats in data
            });
        }, 1000); // updates every 1 second
    }]);
```

This will then allow you to update the model, in the success fuction, and angulars binding will handle updating everything for for

Comment: how do you mean? the only way to update is to get the data from the server, and then update the model. I have assumed you want this to be done automatically at a defined period of time - otherwise it would be manually on click, but the jist would be the same

Comment: Hi DrogoNevets : It's working thanks. I heard that we can use sockets also to update.

Comment: effectively the same thing, just a different way of connecting to the server